# Can we add NoLock inside the SQL view

Tags: sql-server

Can we add NoLock inside the SQL view.

For example :-  I have one view that name is [dbo].[View_1] - **Select * from  [dbo].[View_1]**

My View script is below.

```
SELECT dbo.TestOne.ID AS TestOneId, dbo.TestTwo.ID AS TestTwoId, dbo.TestOne.Name AS NameOne, dbo.TestTwo.Name AS NameTwo
FROM   dbo.TestOne INNER JOIN
             dbo.TestTwo ON dbo.TestOne.ID = dbo.TestTwo.ID
```

Can I use NoLock inside the view which I mentioned below?

```
SELECT dbo.TestOne.ID AS TestOneId, dbo.TestTwo.ID AS TestTwoId, dbo.TestOne.Name AS NameOne, dbo.TestTwo.Name AS NameTwo
FROM   dbo.TestOne **(Nolock)** INNER JOIN
             dbo.TestTwo **(Nolock)** ON dbo.TestOne.ID = dbo.TestTwo.ID
```

Comment: Um, wouldn't it be quicker to try it than to ask us?

Comment: Sorry Dale but  I didn't get your point.

Comment: Just try it, add nolock inside your view and see if it works... takes 2s. Although why do you want to use nolock? Its not something you should do unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if you understand the consequences and accept the problems, then AT LEAST use the current, recommended syntax and not the deprecated version.